# NotFoundHttpException when editing an object

Tags: php, laravel

I have tournament > category > setting, and I need to edit the settings.

For the creation ( http://laravel.dev:8000/tournaments/1/categories/5/settings/create
) , I have no problem, only updating is failing ( http://laravel.dev:8000/tournaments/1/categories/2/settings/5/edit )

I checked the params (1,2,5), and they are OK.

I use my route with resource()

```
        Route::resource('tournaments/{tournamentId}/categories/{categoryId}/settings', 'CategorySettingsController');
```

When I type php artisan route:list, I get this route:

```
GET|HEAD | tournaments/{tournamentId}/categories/{categoryId}/settings/{settings}/edit | tournaments.{tournamentId}.categories.{categoryId}.settings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CategorySettingsController@edit           | auth,roles |
```

So, as for me, everything should be OK, I don't understand why I get a NotFoundHttpException

Any idea????

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the controller actions to see what could be happening?

Comment: can you post the `edit` function? first four five lines would be enough

Comment: right now, I just do a dd() to see if it enters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in RouteServiceProvider.php, I had binding defined:

```
        $router->model('settings','App\Settings');
```

So General settings bindings was conflicting with Category Settings